Nexus issue: jjwt, netty-handler, netty-codec-http
jjwt:0.9.0
netty-handler:4.1.105.Final
netty-codec-http:4.1.105.Final

Facing these nexus issues. Can anyone provide inputs on how we can resolve these nexus issues?
I tried by upgrading jjwt:0.12.0, netty-handler:5.0.0.Alpha1 and netty-codec-http:4.1.108.Final but it was causing issues in functionality of the application.
